How to set up phpMyAdmin on OS X

I am seeing the error message as shown in the screenshot. I have set up all the parameters as shown below. I am also using the MAMP application in this case.
Apache port: 8888
Nginx port: 8888
MySQL port: 3306

/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock';

What can I try next?

Post error messages as text, not as screenshot.

Are you sure the socket path is correct…? The error messages indicates it isn’t.

yes i have created a my.cnf file under conf/ folder with the following inside:
[client]
socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
[mysqld]
socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Apache and Nginx on the same port???

There are many reasons for it

insure that default username and password is "root" (maybe password if blank try this)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

check mySQL serve is running (for check run this)
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 --port=3306

check socket path is proper (for check run this)
ls -la /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

use local ip address instead of localhost
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

Ensure the $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] is correctly set to /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock.

If you prefer using host and port instead of the socket, comment out the socket configuration:
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock';


this might work for you
Thank You

i have set the password to 'root' but i dont understand why am i always prompted with an error in terminal below when i am performing the above checks
"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

That error means you are using the wrong password usually
